# AMF0 parser in ObjectiveC

Tags: c++, objective-c

I am writing an application which connects to an FLV stream and parse data to extract SCRIPTDATAOBJECT.

I successfuly get content of a DATASCRIPTOBJECT and am trying to parse AMF0 data to get some metadata, do you know sample code of AMF0 parsing ?

Thanks a lot.

Thierry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Licensed under MIT style: [Objective-C implementation of the Flash Remoting format (AMF0/AMF3) for servers and clients](http://github.com/nesium/cocoa-amf/tree/master)